# Introductory examples of AdS/CFT duality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, education, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I would like to know, what are the simplest/starting/basic examples that are typically used to introduce students to how AdS/CFT really works? (not the [MAGOO paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111), as I am not sure it has concrete examples that a beginning student can work through)

For example, are the PhD. papers of Maldacena used for this purpose? What about the papers on holographic entanglement entropy (like the ones by Faulkner and Hartman and Shinsei Ryyu and Takayanagi)? Or the papers on worldsheet derivation of the duality like http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703141 (and its predecessors) and http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205297 and the Gopakumar-Vafa papers of '98?

Comment: Assuming that you are familiar to some extent with quantum field theory and supergravity, you will want to start with one of the TASI lectures on AdS/CFT, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253

Comment: There's also Maldacena's own notes for a TASI lecture though maybe not as "easy" http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0309246

Comment: Btw, for those who are not familiar MAGOO = http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111

Comment: The review by Aharony et al (MAGOO) isn't incredibly difficult, at least the first chapters where they discuss the case of Type IIB and N = 4 SYM. If you're having difficulties you should probably read about Dp-branes in any of the string textbooks.
There's also a more explicit but less deep review, hep-th/9902131.

Comment: @Vibert I haven't seen the Hoker and Freedman review but the "problem" with the MAGOO review is that it looks merely like a list of statements/facts without any proof or derivation. Can you point in that review any such pair of concrete calculations which one can work through and convince oneself of the duality?  I mean - it doesn't derive the D3 brane metric whose near horizon become AdS^5Xs^5 - it doesn't show how the N=4 SYM appears - look at its crucial chapter 3 - all the correlation functions are just stated without proof! - it looks like only a little more than a list of references!

Comment: @Vibert Can you say list out some of the important D-brane papers which actually derive any of the necessary ideas? Can you may be list some papers which go through a pedagogic calculation of the duality?

Comment: You might find this course website useful: [Physics 234B at Berkeley, Spring 2013](http://www-theory.lbl.gov/~horava/234B.html)

Comment: @CrazyBudy The sentence you edited out mentions a famous paper and the OP says he is not interested in getting this as an answer. So that sentence should not be edited out, even though user6818 could have edited the link in there too. So I rolled back to v1.

Answer (score 5):

One review I found helpful relates Type IIB superstrings on a maximally supersymmetric plane wave background to N=4 SYM:

[Lectures on the Plane–Wave String/Gauge Theory Duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307101v3) by Jan Christoph Plefka

It might be more conversational than what you're looking for, but this review by Polchinski has some great discussion and probably deserves the mention:

[Introduction to Gauge/Gravity Duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6134) by Joseph Polchinski

One very good, specific set of lecture notes already mentioned but deserving repeat is:

[Supersymmetric Gauge Theories and the AdS/CFT Correspondence](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253v2) by Eric D'Hoker, Daniel Z. Freedman

Comment: As I was asking Vibert above - in any of these reviews can you point to a specific pair (one in gravity one in gauge) of calculation which one can work through to convince oneself of the duality? I am looking for specific examples.